# How can duplicates be dropped, retaining only unique combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 68 | 90 |
| 68 | 91 |
| 68 | 92 |
| 67 | 90 |
| 67 | 91 |
| 67 | 92 |
| 66 | 90 |
| 66 | 91 |
| 66 | 92 |

I'm currently working on isolating unique combinations within my DataFrame. I've attempted to remove duplicates based on two specific columns. However, the DataFrame seems to retain either the first occurrence or the last occurrence, which doesn't serve my purpose. What I'm aiming for is to keep all unique combinations of those two columns. Something like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 68 | 90 |
| 67 | 91 |
| 66 | 92 |

Another possible solution might be:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 68 | 91 |
| 67 | 92 |
| 66 | 90 |

The order of the combinations is not a concern for me.

I'm aware that I can achieve this by iterating over the elements and implementing custom logic. However, I'm specifically interested in finding a pandas-based solution to tackle this issue.

Comment: How is your result a unique combination? You just appear to be finding the unique values in the individual columns.

Comment: df.drop_duplicates() drops duplicates, but what you say you want isn't actually what your desired outputs are

Comment: The problem with your description is that there are only a few datasets where such a solution exists.  Consider `(66,90),(67,90),(68,90)`.  There is no solution.  If you KNOW every A has a record with every B, then it's pretty easy, but you should say that.

Comment: I'm aiming to remove duplicates within each column independently. However, if I use the drop_duplicates method with the subset of column A and column B together, I will end up with the same DataFrame, as it treats the combination of both columns as a unique key. On the other hand, if I drop duplicates based on just one of the columns, I will have repeated values in the other column.

Comment: Use a linear sum assignment, this will ensure unique combinations, see duplicate